# Open JPA error when retrieving bearer access token

Tags: apache, oauth, cxf, openjpa

I am implementing support for OAuth2.0 using Apache CXF. I am also using OpenJPA to persist client and tokens. Access tokens are generated and stored correctly. However, when they are validated and the server tries to retrieve the token from the database I get the exception below. I have checked and the value of the token set into the query is correct. The token record exists in the table. 
The JPA code is generated by the JPA data provider JPACodeDataProvider that comes with CXF

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

```
 <openjpa-3.0.0-r422266:1833209 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.pers
stence.PersistenceException: null
FailedObject: SELECT t FROM BearerAccessToken t WHERE t.tokenKey = :tokenKey [j
va.lang.String]
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1029)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:928)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManage
.java:1035)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:
79)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl$SelectResult.load(SelectImpl.
ava:2382)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:
73)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.InstanceResultObjectProvider.getResul
Object(InstanceResultObjectProvider.java:59)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.ja
a:35)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1262)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1015)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:871)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:802)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.ja
a:541)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:274)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.jav
:290)
        at com.awaresoft.oauthcxf.services.AwareIMDataProvider$1.execute(AwareI
DataProvider.java:31)
        at com.awaresoft.oauthcxf.services.AwareIMDataProvider$1.execute(AwareI
DataProvider.java:1)
        at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.provider.JPAOAuthDataProvider.exec
te(JPAOAuthDataProvider.java:76)
        at com.awaresoft.oauthcxf.services.AwareIMDataProvider.getAccessToken(A
areIMDataProvider.java:22)
        at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AbstractAccessTokenValida
or.getAccessTokenValidation(AbstractAccessTokenValidator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter.validat
Request(OAuthRequestFilter.java:106)
        at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter.filter(
AuthRequestFilter.java:87)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.runContainerRequestFilters(JAX
SUtils.java:1688)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(J
XRSInInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JA
RSInInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseIntercep
orChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInit
ationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(Abstrac
HTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination
ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletCon
roller.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletCon
roller.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSp
ingServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(A
stractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractH
TPServlet.java:225)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(Abstrac
HTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:5
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(App
icationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Application
ilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapper
alve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContext
alve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentic
torBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.
ava:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.
ava:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAcc
ssLogValve.java:650)
```

Comment: Further investigation shows that the actual exception is NullPointerException:
java.lang.NullPointerException in the file org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager on this line:                 
mapping = (ClassMapping) sm.getMetaData();

I also get a warning when I start the system: OpenJPA  WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] openjpa.Runtime - Found no persistent property in "org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.tokens.bearer.BearerAccessToken"

This is probably because the class has no fields itself - it inherits everything from the parent's class. Can it have something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens in JDBCStoreManager in method setInverseRelation in the following code:

```
               ClassMapping cm =
                    (ClassMapping) _conf.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance().getCachedMetaData(pc.getClass());
                FieldMapping[] fmd = cm.getFieldMappings();
```

cm is null and so cm.getFieldMappings() crashes. ClassMapping is not in the metadata cache. For some reason the cache only has original classes, but pc.getClass returns an ENHANCED class. Looks very much like a bug in Open JPA. Can anyone confirm this?